# TPL FromAsync with TaskScheduler and TaskFactory

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am trying to create a Task pipeline/ordered scheduler in combination with using `TaskFactory.FromAsync`.

I want to be able to fire off web service requests (using `FromAsync` to use I/O completion ports) but maintain their order and only have a single one executing at any one time.

At the moment I do not use `FromAsync` so I can do `TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>api.DoSyncWebServiceCall())` and rely on the `OrderedTaskScheduler` used by the `TaskFactory` to ensure that only one request is outstanding.

I assumed that this behaviour would stay when using the `FromAsync` method but it does not:

```
TaskFactory<Stuff> taskFactory = new TaskFactory<Stuff>(new OrderedTaskScheduler());
var t1 = taskFactory.FromAsync((a, s) => api.beginGetStuff(a, s), a => api.endGetStuff(a));
var t2 = taskFactory.FromAsync((a, s) => api.beginGetStuff(a, s), a => api.endGetStuff(a));
var t3 = taskFactory.FromAsync((a, s) => api.beginGetStuff(a, s), a => api.endGetStuff(a));
```

All of these `beginGetStuff` methods get called within the `FromAsync` call (so although they are dispatched in order but there are `n` api calls occurring at the same time).

There is an overload of `FromAsync` that takes a TaskScheduler:

```
public Task FromAsync(
    IAsyncResult asyncResult,
    Action<IAsyncResult> endMethod,
    TaskCreationOptions creationOptions,
    TaskScheduler scheduler
)
```

but the docs say:

> The TaskScheduler that is used to schedule the task that executes the end method.

And as you can see, it takes the already constructed `IAsyncResult`, not a `Func<IAsyncResult>`.

Does this call for a custom `FromAsync` method or am I missing something?  Can anyone suggest where to start on this implementation?

Cheers,

EDIT:

I want to abstract this behaviour away from the caller so, as per the behaviour of `TaskFactory` (with a specialized `TaskScheduler`), I need the Task to be returned immediately - this Task will not only encapsulate the `FromAsync` Task but also the queueing of that task whilst it awaits its turn to execute.

One possible solution:

```
class TaskExecutionQueue
{
    private readonly OrderedTaskScheduler _orderedTaskScheduler;
    private readonly TaskFactory _taskFactory;
    public TaskExecutionQueue(OrderedTaskScheduler orderedTaskScheduler)
    {
        _orderedTaskScheduler = orderedTaskScheduler;
        _taskFactory = new TaskFactory(orderedTaskScheduler);

    }

    public Task<TResult> QueueTask<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskGenerator)
    {
        return _taskFactory.StartNew(taskGenerator).Unwrap();
    }
}
```

However, this utilizes a thread whilst the `FromAsync` call is occurring.  Ideally I'd not have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided on a custom solution here... The locks are messy and undesired but at the moment, this does the job I want.

```
public interface ITaskExecutionQueue
{
    Task<TResult> QueueTask<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskGenerator);
    Task<TResult> QueueTask<TResult>(Task<Task<TResult>> taskGenerator);
    int OutstandingTaskCount { get; }
    event EventHandler OutstandingTaskCountChanged;
}

/// This class ensures that only a single Task is executed at any one time.  They are executed sequentially in order being queued.
/// The advantages of this class over OrderedTaskScheduler is that you can use any type of Task such as FromAsync (I/O Completion ports) 
/// which are not able to be scheduled using a traditional TaskScheduler.
/// Ensure that the `outer` tasks you queue are unstarted.  E.g. <![CDATA[
/// _taskExeQueue.QueueTask(new Task<Task<TResult>>(() => StartMyRealTask()));
/// ]]>
class OrderedTaskExecutionQueue : ITaskExecutionQueue
{
    private readonly Queue<Task> _queuedTasks = new Queue<Task>();
    private Task _currentTask;
    private readonly object _lockSync = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Queues a task for execution
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="taskGenerator">An unstarted Task that creates your started real-work task</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<TResult> QueueTask<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskGenerator)
    {
        return QueueTask(new Task<Task<TResult>>(taskGenerator));
    }

    public Task<TResult> QueueTask<TResult>(Task<Task<TResult>> taskGenerator)
    {
        Task<TResult> unwrapped = taskGenerator.Unwrap();
        unwrapped.ContinueWith(_ =>
                               {
                                   EndTask();
                                   StartNextTaskIfQueued();
                               }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        lock (_lockSync)
        {
            _queuedTasks.Enqueue(taskGenerator);

            if (_currentTask == null)
            {
                StartNextTaskIfQueued();
            }
        }

        TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.TrySetFromTaskIncomplete(unwrapped);

        OutstandingTaskCountChanged.Raise(this);

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private void EndTask()
    {
        lock (_lockSync)
        {
            _currentTask = null;
            _queuedTasks.Dequeue();
        }

        OutstandingTaskCountChanged.Raise(this);
    }

    private void StartNextTaskIfQueued()
    {
        lock (_lockSync)
        {
            if (_queuedTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                _currentTask = _queuedTasks.Peek();

                _currentTask.RunSynchronously();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Includes the currently executing task.
    /// </summary>
    public int OutstandingTaskCount
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockSync)
            {
                return _queuedTasks.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler OutstandingTaskCountChanged;
}
```

Takes in an unstarted `Task<Task<TResult>>` - this allows the queue to decide when to execute it and begin the `FromAsync` call (which is the inner task).  Usage:

```
Task<Task<TResult>> queueTask = new Task<Task<TResult>>(() => Task.Factory.FromAsync(beginAction, endAction));
Task<TResult> asyncCallTask = _taskExecutionQueue.QueueTask(queueTask);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot schedule IO tasks because they do not have a thread associated with them. The Windows Kernel provides thread-less IO operations. Starting these IOs does not involve managed code and the `TaskScheduler` class does not come into play.

So you have to delay starting the IO until you are sure you actually want the network to be hit. You could use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` to throttle the amount of tasks currently running. Await the result of that method before starting the individual IO and awaiting that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use [TPL Dataflow](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow).

You can define a "block" that receives a stream of asynchronous delegates and executes them one at a time (waiting until each one is complete before starting the next):

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>(func => func());
```

Then, to fire off a web service request:

```
block.Post(() => Task.Factory.FromAsync(...));
```

or (which I prefer):

```
block.Post(() => client.GetStuffAsync(a, b, c));
```

The `ActionBlock` approach is fine if you just want to execute the tasks. If you want to produce a stream of output, then take a look at `TransformBlock`:

```
var block = new TransformBlock<Func<Task<Stuff>>, Stuff>(func => func());
```

You fire off your requests the same way, and you can get the results by calling `Receive` or `ReceiveAsync`.

Comment: Now that I think about it - if the OP wants only one request outstanding... why doesn't he just use a loop? If he can do that he probably should prefer that to TPL dataflow.

Comment: That was my first thought, but from his description it sounded like he wanted more of a "fire and forget" kind of usage pattern.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - that sounds very interesting and something I'd like to check out.  Apologies for not making my question clearer but you're right, my use case is where I can handle the Task immediately, despite it being queued before execution (same behaviour as TaskFactory with a specialized task scheduler gives you).  I'm not yet sure if TPL Dataflow will enable this but will take a look!  Cheers,